# Why does my onClick js function call only work once per page load?

Tags: javascript, html, rss, yql, setattribute

I am trying to display an rss feed from google news using yql. Currently, if you enter a zip code into the form, it works once, but I cannot enter another code without refreshing the page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
    
    
        
            P1

```
        <script>   
        function top_stories(o){  
            var items = o.query.results.item;  
            var output = '';  
            var no_items=items.length; 

            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
            var title = items[i].title;  
            var link = items[i].link;  
            var desc = items[i].description;  
           output += "<h3><a href='" + link + "'>"+title+"</a></h3>" + desc + "<hr/>";  
            }
         document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;    
         }  
         </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="input" action="" method="get" id="zc">
        Zip Code: <input id="zip" type="text" name="zip">
    <input id ="zipbutton" type="Button" value="Submit"    onClick="showDiv(document.getElementById('zc').zip.value);" >

    <div id="results"  ></div> 
    <script id="yql"></script>
    <script>    
    function showDiv(zip) {             
    var a = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public /yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%20%3D%20'http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.com%2Fnews%3Fgeo%3D" + zip + "%26output%3Drss'%0A&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=top_stories";
     document.getElementById("yql").setAttribute("src",a);                              
        }
    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Don't use `onclick` on the submit button, use `submit` on the form (there are  ways to submit the form without clicking the button). Use `return showDiv(...)` in the event listener and add `return false` to `showDiv` function to prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create new `<script>` element for every click.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("src", a);
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This almost works. The only problem is, I seem to only be able to append to body[0] while the "results" div is the first child of body in order to get the links to show up. This isn't so bad, but it would be nice to have the form stay above the links. The bigger problem is, the button only works sometimes. I have to click it several times for it to work. Any ideas on how to fix this?